# How to do Summation of a vector product in language R

Tags: r, function, vector, summarize

I would like to do the summation of product of all the elements of two vectors in R language, but something goes wrong. This is my data definition:

```
> alpha <- 1/24
> a <- c(-5, -2, 1)
> b <- c(alpha*3, alpha*2, 1-5*alpha)
```

Then I'm trying:

```
> result <- sum(a*b)
> result
[1] 8.326673e-17
```

And I expect the result is zero, but it's not.
To explain better, I would like to compute this summation:

```
(a[1]*b[1]) + (a[2]*b[2]) + (a[3]*b[3])
```

That should be:

```
(-5*alpha*3)+(-2*alpha*2)+(1*(1-alpha*5)) = (-5*1/24*3)+(-2*1/24*2)+(1*(1-5*1/24)) = 0
```

Comment: This is simply round-off error.  See [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/4752675)

Comment: Worth noting additionally that sum(a*b) is correct syntactically, and G5W  is referring to the result of 8.326673e-17 ~=~ 0.

Comment: You can still get a zero. Maintain the values as fractions then just compute them: `b <- MASS::fractions(c(alpha*3, alpha*2, 1-5*alpha));sum(b*a)`

Comment: @Onyambu Great, it works by simply doing:  `result <- fractions(sum(a*b))`

Comment: Yes I know that works too

Comment: @RuiBarradas I understand, but I was also looking for a good solution to avoid the problem, as is the one suggested by Onyambu.

Comment: @Glk-78 In general, rather than testing for exact equality, you test with a given tolerance. In your case, you would do something like `abs(sum(a*b)) < 1e-8` or whatever epsilon is appropriate for your use case.